# Выходные типы в методах Java

Tags: java, методы

Что делать, если у меня в методе кроме, например, типа integer, может возвращаемое значение может быть null?

Comment: Используйте объект `Integer`.

Comment: нет, не используйте Integer. это антипаттерн. не стоит возвращать null в своем методе.  в данном случае есть несколько решений. например, выбрасывайте исключение либо верните Optional<Integer>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучшим решением до Java 8, будет возврат обертки Integer над примитивным типом int.
Для Java 8 и выше был введен параметризированный класс Optional, который и стоит использовать.